# When running echinus can the scrollbars and similar window elements be skinned?

Tags: linux, window-manager, gtk

I see on [this website](http://plhk.ru/) screenshots number 5 and 6 -- what is used to to get these style of scrollbars? When I launch Opera I get a very ugly scrollbar that does not fit the look of the window manager whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to load a gtk theme by creating a symlink (`~/.gtkrc-2.0`) that points to the gtk theme's gtkrc (`/usr/share/themes/themename/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` or `~/.themes/themename/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` depending where the theme is installed and assuming it's a gtk 2.0 theme).